# React redirect when promise resolved?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a project in react that uses react router.  I want to redirect to another page when a promise is resolved like so:

```
  handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    login(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(response => {

      return <Link to="/new_page"/>
    }).catch(err => {
        return "nothing";
    });
  }
```

In theory, when the response is successfully created, it should redirect to "new_page".  However in practice nothing happens. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald yep!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `history.push`

```
handleSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  login(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(response => {
    history.push('/new_page')
  }).catch(err => {
      return "nothing";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
<Redirect to="/new_page"/>
```

or something like

```
history.push("/new_page")
```